# Why doesn't poll wakeup when socket timed out with SO_RCVTIMEO?

Tags: c, network-programming

I'm writing an echoing TCP server which handles a maximum of 10 simultaneous connections. It has an idle timeout(when there is no new connection or no new data from sockets) and a socket timeout (when the client does not send anything new in xx time).

I handled the first part with timeout parameter in poll(). For the second part, for each new connection, I set the socket with the option:

setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &socketTimeout, sizeof(struct timeval)

I expect that when the socket timed out, it will wake poll() up and when I call read() after it will just return -1, and I can do my things. But it seems not to be the case. SO_RCVTIMEO seems to have no effect for poll(), what did I miss?

Comment: Why would you expect a socket's recv timeout to be triggered by poll()? It's not trying to read any data from the socket.

Comment: Hmmm. I assume poll will call read on each socket intermittenly, or something like that. Otherwise how would it know if there is any data available for read?

Comment: The details vary depending on OS, but generally it involves one part of the kernel notifying another part that the socket has data ready to read.

Comment: In this article : https://notes.shichao.io/unp/ch6/#tcp-echo-server-revisited

they list the exact conditions when poll is triggered. There is this line: "The presence of an error for a TCP connection can be considered either normal data or an error (POLLERR). In either case, a subsequent read will return –1 with errno set to the appropriate value. This handles conditions such as the receipt of an RST or a timeout." I assume a "timeout" here is the the timeout condition imposed by SO_RCVTIMEO?

Comment: No... Think low level tcp timeouts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>It would be beneficial to link the article you mentioned in comments.</strike>

Meanwhile, quoting `man 7 socket`,

> Timeouts only have effect for system calls that perform socket I/O (e.g., read(2), recvmsg(2), send(2), sendmsg(2)); timeouts have no effect for select(2), poll(2), epoll_wait(2), and so on.

So for timeout to happen, a `read` must be called. `poll` only monitor data availability.

Comment: That settles the issue. Thank you!